# RDP using Windows CE 7 to Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, windows-ce

I use a Motorola device with Windows CE 07.00.2806 and try to connect to a Windows Server 2008 R2 getting the following error message:

`„An authentication error has occurred (Code: 0x80090304).“`

Already checked the security settings on the server, rdp connections should have the right permissions. also tried different logins with / without domain and different users, all of them had admin priviledges on the server --> no success so far.

What am I missing?

I've read about a possible update fix on [this site (FIX: "0x80090304" authentication error)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2826742/en-us), but couldn't figure out how to update a windows ce device. Could this be the solution and how can I do this?

#### EDIT 1

[image: server security settings]

Comment: On the Windows Server, have you disabled the requirement for Network Level Authentication?

Comment: yes, see my updated question with the picture

Comment: You can download the latest monthly CE 7 updates from MS and then apply them directly to the CE device, is that your question?  Because that KB article definitely looks like your issue and your fix.

Comment: And how exactly can I do that? The downloadable exe file is not installable on the ce device, but opens a setup window on my windows 8 pc asking for a product key...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved using a special update provided by the vendor of my device. To use the mentioned update from the KB article from Microsoft you have to use the CE image builder framework from Microsoft to build complete .iso-images for CE-devices. This was unneccessary and should be avoided as almost updates are provided by the device manufacturers.